# Prevent tomcat from reusing deleted classes

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am working on a java website using Netbeans and Tomcat.
I renamed one of my class and this now leas to a cast error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: package.NewClassName cannot be cast to package.OldClassName
```

Even making a "Clean and Build Main Project" doesn't fix anything. All the removed classes that do not appear at all in the source files keep being generated in the build.
As a result, the old servlet is still being used, which leads to the problem aforementioned.

How can I delete for good those obsolete classes?

Comment: Did you updated the web.xml?

Comment: Where is this file?

Comment: inside Web Folder->WEB-INF->web.xml

Comment: Thanks, what should I update?

Comment: inside <servlet-name>newname.java</sevlet-name> &</servlet-class>newname.class</servlet-class>

Comment: I only have a web.xml in the NetBeans and the NetBeans' AppData folder. Should I add one in my src directory (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/)?

Comment: No, not required, the rule is web.xml should reside inside WEB-INF, after you update, try rebuilding.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. Which web.xml file am I supposed to edit?

Comment: The one which is inside WEB-INF!

Comment: I created a web.xml file inside WEB-INF and added `<servlet><servlet-name>PagesProtection.java</servlet-name><servlet-class>PagesProtection.class</servlet-class></servlet>`, but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

check deployment folder of tomcat, whether this project is changed when "Clean and Build Main Project"
if no, redeploy this project

Comment: There is no folder in the name of my application in my tomcat/webapps folder, also the Netbeans history seems to indicate that this is indeed the tomcat installation used.

Comment: one way is worth to try —— create a new java ee project, and import this old project